# Flutter: Change internet connection when using "flutter run"

Tags: flutter, dart, wifi

At the moment I have my phone hooked up, and I use `flutter run` and the app works great, with no bugs. Then I build an app-debug.apk, install that and turn off my wifi one small part of the app stops working because it can't connect to Firestore, but other parts can connect to Firestore, and everything else is fine. If I use Wifi it works, but not if I am on LTE, I can't figure out why this one part doesn't work when I'm in wireless mode. But when I plug it back in it works again. So I can't debug it because the phone's always unplugged when it happens. I feel like the `flutter run` command may be using my computer's internet, and that would be why I can't duplicate it, so I want to use `flutter run` but use my wireless carrier. I turned off wifi on my phone, but that didn't change anything. How do I use `flutter run` with a wireless internet connection?

Comment: Does the same behavior happens when using `--release` flag ?

Comment: Interesting... it seems when I use `flutter build apk --release` it works fine. I was using `flutter build apk --debug` Do you know what's up with that?

Comment: Is your page not working using native plugins, or it's just plain dart code ?

Comment: Oh ya I got a bunch of plugins. Firebase mostly. I think that may be the problem, somethign weird with the firebase connection.